# MVC Listbox - Show Image in Listbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

Can we show images in MVC Listbox?

Model declaration

```
public List<SelectListItem> Type { get; set; }      //Will hold listbox items
public string[]SelectedType { get; set; }       //Will hold selected items
```

Data for listbox

```
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "A. Best seller ", Value = "1", Selected = false });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "B. Special offer callout", Value = "2", Selected = true });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "C. Promotion", Value = "3", Selected = false });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "4. Banner Large", Value = "4", Selected = false });
```

model.Type = items;

View Binding

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedType, Model.Type, new { id = "listType", Multiple = "multiple", Size = 15, style = "width: 100%;" })
```

It successfully display the listbox as below:
[image]

Can I bind or display some image with it? Image can be stored on File System or? and name the image as as ID e.g. 1.png, 2.png etc.

Any way to display image here?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. You may create some html helper for listbox or some third party control (Google for it). But it is not possible in traditional listbox.

Comment: Yes it seems need to use some third party. I see some free but no open source so far

Comment: Why you want it in listbox? is it inside some form?

Comment: Yes. It is part of a big form

Comment: You can use checkbox array with image which also give you facility of multiple selection and also send array of selected items to the controller action.